# Can you locate an order that has not been shipped?

Tags: stock, magento2.4.2, default-values

We have "missing stock" that is affecting the default stock and saleable quantity by 1 or 2.

I understand that once the order has been shipped, this should reset it. However, there are a few products that never reset or get shipped. I just want to locate what order they are 'allocated' to so we can get our stock levels correct.